# Redirect a Named Pipe in a perl loop

Tags: bash, perl, pipe, named-pipes

Having a named pipe as a source

```
shell1> mkfifo ~/myfifo
shell1> tee -a ~/myfifo
ciao
```

Why doesn't the following command print out any message?

```
shell2> cat ~/myfifo | perl -ane 'print "testa\n"' | cat
```

Whilst removing the last command all run as supposed

```
shell2> cat ~/myfifo | perl -ane 'print "testa\n"'
testa
```

Comment: I think `cat` is waiting for an `EOF` marker so it will not print anything before that arrives. Try press `CTRL-D` in `shell1`, then the output arrives in `shell2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `STDOUT` of the Perl process is not connected to a tty, autoflushing is turned off. This is the case when piping the output from the Perl process to `cat` instead of printing it to the terminal. This causes the `cat` command to hang, waiting for input from the Perl process.

You can fix this by turning on autoflush for STDOUT:

```
cat ~/myfifo | perl -ane 'STDOUT->autoflush(1); print "testa\n"' | cat
```

alternativly you can use the [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) command:

```
cat ~/myfifo | unbuffer -p perl -ane 'print "testa\n"' | cat
```

Comment: Or just not use cat at all. `perl -ne 'blah' ~/myfifo`

Comment: @Håkon Brilliant. Brilliant, you solved my dubt. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: @Shawn The example was useless, just to prove the missing output.